# How can i do String manipulation from list values like below

Tags: java

I want to replace the string with list values dynamically without hard coding.
like 'list.get(0)'

In first iteration ==> `str = str.replace("{Name}", 'One');`

In second iteration ==> `str = str.replace("{subInterfaceId}", 'Two');`

Thanks in advance.

```
String str = "Iamstillquite/{Name}/newtoJava/programm/ingandIam/{subInterfaceId}/tryingtoupdate/anexisting";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("One");
list.add("Two");    

for (String s : list) {
    str = str.replace("{Name}", s);
}
```

expected Output :

```
String finalstr = "Iamstillquite/One/newtoJava/programm/ingandIam/Two/tryingtoupdate/anexisting";
```

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way to do this is with regex:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("One");
list.add("Two");
String str = "Iamstillquite/{Name}/newtoJava/programm/ingandIam/{subInterfaceId}/tryingtoupdate/anexisting";
String regex = "(?<=^[^\\{]+)\\{.*?\\}";
for (String s : list)
{
    str = str.replaceAll(regex, s);
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
Iamstillquite/One/newtoJava/programm/ingandIam/Two/tryingtoupdate/anexisting
```

**Benefits:** You won't have to change any of your existing data, and regex is ***incredibly*** useful for searching and replacing stuff.

*Also,* you can keep the input String `str` as it is, unlike what you'll have to do for other answers given here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("One");
    list.add("Two");
    int counter = 0;
    String str = new String("Iamstillquite/{Name0}/newtoJava/programm/ingandIam/{Name1}/tryingtoupdate/anexisting");
    for (String s : list) {
        str = str.replace("{Name" + counter + "}", s);
        counter++;
    }
```

You might find useful using a counter to make the replacement easier. That's why you'll need to name the strings you want to replace as {Name0}, {Name1}, {Name2}...although it has no difficulty because you could do it in a loop if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Map` for that. It maps a key (`{Name}`) to a value (`One`).

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("{Name}", "One");
map.put("{subInterfaceId}", "Two");

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    str = str.replace(key, map.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and Matcher to replace anything inside {} using below solution:

```
        Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("(\\{[\\w]+\\})");
        int index = 0;
        Matcher m1 = pat1.matcher(str);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(m1.find() && index<list.size()){ //checking index is necessary to not throw `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`
            m1.appendReplacement(sb, list.get(index));
            index += 1;
        }
        m1.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb);
```

Output:

```
Iamstillquite/One/newtoJava/programm/ingandIam/Two/tryingtoupdate/anexisting
```